# Repeating last lines before automatic frame break on new beamer page

Tags: allowframebreaks

Is it possible to repeat the last lines before the automatic frame break on the new beamer page?

Essentially, I want to display

```
\begin{frame}
A
B
...
Z
\end{frame}
```

as

```
\begin{frame}
A
...
P
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
K
...
Z
\end{frame}
```

where last line P and first line K are chosen to use the available space (so there is overlap).

Comment: What you mean with "repeat"?  That new slide in frame start with last line from previous slide? Evaluate please. Also provide a small complete document which we can test in see what your problem is actually.

Answer (score 1):

The beamer class documentation recommends:

> Do not use the option allowframebreaks except for long bibliographies.
>
> [...]
>
> Using the allowframebreaks option invites the creation of horrible, endless presentations that resemble more a “paper projected on the wall” than a presentation.

To answer the question concretely: If I were you, I would divide the one long slide into individual frames just like in your second code snippet.